# How do I remove directory name in URL with htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the name of a folder (which I need for organizational purposes in the backend and template system).

My URL is like so: http://www.example.com/states/texas/houston/

and I need to remove *states* fro that string.

I'm using this in .htaccess file (I'm using Wordpress, so there's some added code, and maybe the problem is there):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^states/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, it's not removing states folder in the URL

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Use R redirect flag :


`RewriteRule ^states/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]`

Comment: yes, I tried that as well, but doesn't work. I also tried `RewriteRule ^states/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` but nothing, it seems like there's another issue :(